# Alternative to SHOUTcast server?

Tags: streaming, audio, internet

I have a streaming system that generates an MP3 stream as output for the listeners. This streaming system runs on a modern 64bit linux machine and on this machine the old SHOUTcast 1.9.8 server doesn't work properly. I've tried to use the Icecast 2.3.2 as an alternative, but had problems with that as well.

Does someone know a good alternative to serve an MP3 stream on a linux server that is not SHOUTcast 1.9.8 nor Icecast 2.3.2?

I don't want to use Icecast 2.3.2 because it doesn't support MP3 officially.

Comment: I've used icecast with great success with MPEG Layer3 streaming..

Comment: I've used red5 with success

Comment: Product recommendations, including alternatives recon, is off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Icecast most certainly supports MP3.

Actually, the SHOUTcast-compatible servers do not care what the data type is.  You can send them anything.  (Don't believe me?  Telnet into one, send some text, and watch it come out the client side!)

Your viable choices:

- [SHOUTcast DNAS 2.0](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools)
- [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/)

If you have problems with either of those, perhaps you should post about resolving those instead.

Comment: The problems with Icecast 2.3.2 where on the client side. On windows the stream was not very stable and couldn't be listened to.

Comment: What client?  "On Windows" is way too vague, as the operating system has little to do with it.

Comment: With any player. Winamp, VLC, and so on. The only player where it worked partly was the Windows Media Player.

Comment: I hate to say I don't believe you, but I don't.  You mean to tell me that you had your server and clients on the same LAN, and you have tried several pieces of software under several operating systems, and you experienced buffer underruns on all but Windows Media Player on occasion?  And you claim the server is at fault?  Are you **absolutely sure** you ruled out everything?  Have you packet sniffed to see if the data was getting to the client in time?  Did you verify that the source stream was sending enough data?  In fact, did you use the same source as you did with SHOUTcast DNAS?

Comment: Not the same LAN. The server was running on a 64bit Linux machine on the net and the clients where normal users. On Linux clients everything works well but windows clients have problems with these mp3 streams from Icecast server. The source in all tests was a DJ streaming MP3 directly into the server. The windows users can listen to a SHOUTcast on the same server normally but not to a Icecast MP3 stream because of buffer underruns.

Comment: Do a test on the same network, and get back to us.